# Rest API - 404 Not Found при запросе @DELETE

Tags: java, rest, http-status-code-404

При выполнении [примера](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/basic_grizzly_jersey/jersey-grizzly-json-service.html#section6) с Rest API c сайта Oracle, при запросе @DELETE выпадает ошибка сервера 404 Not Found.

Вот сам код:

Note.java

```
public class Note {
    private final UUID id;
    private final String title;

    private Note(NoteBuilder builder){
        this.id = builder.id;
        this.title = builder.title;
    }

    public Note(){
        Note not = new Note.NoteBuilder().id().build();
        this.id = not.getId();
        this.title = not.getTitle();
    }

    public Note(UUID id, String title) {
        Note not = new Note.NoteBuilder().id()
                .title(title)
                .build();

        this.id = not.getId();
        this.title = not.getTitle();
    }

    public UUID getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "ID: " + id
                + " Title: " + title;
    }

    public static class NoteBuilder{
        private UUID id;
        private String title = "";

        public NoteBuilder id(){
            this.id =  UUID.randomUUID();
            return this;
        }

        public NoteBuilder title(String title){
            this.title = title;
            return this;
        }

        public Note build(){
            return new Note(this);
        }
    }
}
```

NoteList.java

```
public class NoteList {
    private static final CopyOnWriteArrayList<Note> nList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    static {
        nList.add(
                new Note.NoteBuilder().id()
                        .title("1 заметка")
                        .build()
        );

        nList.add(
                new Note.NoteBuilder().id()
                        .title("2 заметка")
                        .build()
        );
    }
    private NoteList() {
    }

    public static CopyOnWriteArrayList<Note> getInstance(){
            return nList;
        }
}
```

NoteService.java

```
@Path("/notes")
public class NoteService {

    private final CopyOnWriteArrayList<Note> nList = NoteList.getInstance();

    @GET
    @Path("/all")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getAll(){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
       // return nList.toString();
        return gson.toJson(nList);
    }

    @POST 
    @Path("/add")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response addNote(Note note){
        nList.add(note);
        return Response.status(201).build();
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/remove/{id}")
    public Response deleteCustomer(@PathParam("id") UUID id){
        Predicate<Note> note = n -> n.getId() == id;
        if (nList.removeIf(note)) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
        }else {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }

    }
}
```

При запросе `@GET` выводится следующее:

> [{"id": "313695e0-72a5-4aab-9047-fbec516dab4f", "title":"1 заметка",
>   "id": "9e4b9d09-347b-439c-aecf-b259b086f987","title":"2 заметка"}]

Правда почему то в не в виде дерева. Но тем не менее, это всё равно объект `JSON`, как я понимаю.
Запрос `@POST` также выполняется без проблем. Но `@DELETE` - ошибка 404.

Запрос `@DELETE` подаю через [сURL](https://curl.haxx.se/) в таком виде:

```
curl -X DELETE -i http://localhost:8080/test_war_exploded/notes/remove/9e4b9d09-347b-439c-aecf-b259b086f987
```

Данная ошибка показывает на то, что объекта с этим `id` нет, но `@GET` же показывает что есть. Что не так-то, не могу понять этот момент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Predicate<Note> note = n -> n.getId().equals(id);
```